# How do I refactor a class with lots of operations which all require its internal data?

Tags: oop, refactoring

### My Problem

I have a class with just a few fields but which represents a relatively complicated data structure. This class is central in my program and over time I found myself adding more and more functionality into it, making things a mess. Since (almost) all of its methods rely on its internal fields, I could not think of a way to move some of the methods elsewhere, even though most methods are independent of each other. **How can I refactor this class to make it simpler and reduce the number of methods which are directly implemented in it?**

### More Information

The class in question represents a sort of automaton. It supports a ton of operations such as retrieving information about it, performing various binary operations between it and other automata, querying for specific information stored inside it, saving it to file, etc. Almost all of these operations depend on the precise implementation of the class - in my specific case I maintain an edge-set-based implementation, but other implementations were also used in the past and might be used again in the future.

Except for a narrow set of basic helper methods which are commonly used, most methods are independent of each other.

The language I am using is Java, but I'm hoping for general answers which could be applied to any statically-typed, object-oriented language.

### What I've Tried

I tried refactoring it somehow to multiple types, but each of its operations require access to most of its fields, and I'm hesitant about migrating these operations elsewhere because I can't think of a way to do that without exposing the class's implementation.

I'm also not sure *where* I should migrate the operations to, assuming they are indeed independent of the implementation. An external utility class? An abstract base type? Will appreciate any input about this.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could remodel the data that your class holds, so that instead of holding the data directly, it holds objects that hold the data? Then you could move the methods that manipulate that data into the new classes, leaving the original class as a sort of container / dispatcher class.

Comment: That's an interesting idea, but since the methods need access to all the data then wouldn't it be a problem moving them into an object which contains only part of the data they need? And if I will store all the data in just one object then I'm back to square one, as it will grow into a complicated monster.

Comment: Do your automaton classes all have (very) different implementations, then?

Comment: These problems usually arise as a result of wrong design: more specifically principles such as separation of concerns and single responsibility. If your datastructure accesses your data, then it is wrong. You can't have nice solution, as long as you have this issue.

Comment: It's difficult to give further suggestions without a little more information - can you give more background / detail?

Comment: @RoryHunter yes, the implementations can potentially be quite different. Regarding more information - what exactly are you looking for?

Comment: @NazarMerza the internal data is already stored in built-in language data structures. But even if I move the fields and their most basic accessors to another type, won't that just move the problem to the class which will hold a reference to an object of that type?

Comment: The crux of the whole matter is working where the common data or - perhaps in your case - where the common operations are. Maybe you have different internal implementations in your classes, but common methods in each. If that were true then you could "dumb down" the current classes and put the common logic in one place. Actually, I think what I'm trying to describe is this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern